# How to use according to in a sentence

Tags: grammar

1. if I use according to in a sentence, is it following with noun always? And is it coming in first or in last.

> According to the police report, you are a traitor.
>   Or
>   You are traitor, according to the police report.

2. Is it right if I use (as stated) instead of according to

> As stated in a police report, you are a traitor.

Answer (score 1):

The first way you wrote it is better, but both ways are true.
"According to" is followed by a noun, like you wrote.

However, "according to" does not have the same meaning as "as stated in" in your example.

"According to the report, you are a traitor" means I am only speaking in reference to what is written. I don't know if you are a traitor or not, but according to this report you are. I'm basing my statement on this report; if you would disprove the report then I would not know one way or the other if you are a traitor.

"As stated in this report, you are a traitor" implies independent knowledge. 
It's as if I'm saying "I know that you are a traitor, which is what it says in this report."
The phrase "as stated in this report" is a simple reference to what is written. 
But even if you would disprove the report, I still know (or have evidence, etc.) that you're a traitor.

So there's a difference between the two phrases "according to" and "as stated in."

Answer (score 0):

"According to" in that context also means: based on information from, in full this phrase is used like this, very simply: this said **_ so _**.

This phrase is typically used to make a logical argument from authority. 1. **So yes, a noun will usually follow "according to".**

2. **Yes, "as stated" seems to be an appropriate substitute for according to.**

examples of using according to in a sentence:

According to Albert Einstein space and time are intrinsically connected.

According to the weatherman it is going to rain today.

According to this notification my laptop needs an update.

Comment: Thanks. so, it is correct based on information from police report, you are a traitor. can I put article before or after police